# Remove a div from .get() request

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

How do I `remove` a div (lets name it `div_2`) from `div_1` which is been loaded via .get() with this code:

```
    $.get('mysite.html', {}, function(data) {
       var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
       var $div_1 = $response.find('#div_1');
       $('#container-div').append($div_1);      
    },'html');
```

I need it to be done **only** with this code, so no .load() and etc.

I tried this:

```
    $.get('mysite.html', {}, function(data) {
       var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
       var $div_1 = $response.find('#div_1');
       $('#container-div').append($div_1, function() {
        $('#div_2').remove();
    });       
    },'html');
```

Didn't work. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've parsed the data and stored the parsed result in `$response`. Just as you've found `div_1` in it with `find`, you can do the same to find `div_2` in it — and then `remove` it. Either initially after parsing, or after finding `#div_1`:

```
$.get('mysite.html', {}, function(data) {
   var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
   var $div_1 = $response.find('#div_1');
   $div_1.find("#div_2").remove(); // <====================
   $('#container-div').append($div_1);      
},'html');
```

Comment: Just to clarify, appended `div_1` will be not containing the removed section at the moment of `.append`?

Comment: @AndrewK - Right, the code removes the div from it before it's appended. (It would also work even if you appended `#div_1` and then removed `#div_2` from it afterward -- the browser won't try to render it in-between those two statements -- but it's probably a bit cleaner to remove it first.)

Comment: A tiny follow up here, I have a hq images inside divs witch is loading via `.get()` inside `main page`, about 4-7 get request per one page and its kinda "heavy" on load since they all load simultaneously. Is it make any sense if I queue this requests somehow? If it is what is I will be appreciated if you point me in the right direction

Comment: @AndrewK - I'm fairly sure that's covered by a few questions and answers here, I'd do a thorough search. The browser already queues them, of course... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from `$div_1` before appending.

```
var $div_1 = $response.find('#div_1');
$('#div_2', $div_1).remove(); // or $div_1.find('#div_2').remove();
$('#container-div').append($div_1);
```

`.append()` doesn't take a callback function.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use removeChild method from javascript

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#div_2');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```